# Formulating a Promise - React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, es6-promise

I am trying to make a promise but haven't been able to grasp some concept I think.

here is the code:

```
import { transferUtility } from 'react-native-s3'; 
import { S3Options, BucketName } from '../config/S3'; 
import ImageResizer from 'react-native-image-resizer'; 
import { dirPicutures, dirPicuturesCompressed } from '../config/DirStorage'; 
import { updateAttachmentUploaded } from '../database/dbactions/attachment';

var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');


function compressImage(imagePath, compressedImagePath) {

  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

      console.log("imagePath: " + imagePath, "compressedImagePath: " + compressedImagePath);

      ImageResizer.createResizedImage(imagePath, 800, 600, 'JPEG', 50, 0)
      .then( (resizedImageUri) => {
         console.log("resizedImageUri", resizedImageUri);

         const resizedImagePath = resizedImageUri.replace("file:/", "");

         //check if resized image exists in the cache
         //if exists then move it to the desired folder
         RNFS.exists(resizedImagePath).then( (result) => {
           console.log(resizedImagePath, result);

           RNFS.mkdir(dirPicuturesCompressed)
           .then( () => {
             console.log("mkdir");

             RNFS.moveFile(resizedImagePath, compressedImagePath)
               .then( () => {
                 console.log('RESIZED FILE MOVED');
                 resolve(true);
               })//end promise moveFile
               .catch((err) => {
                 console.log("resized image move file error", err);
                 reject(false);
               });

           })//end of promise from mkdir
           .catch( (error) => {
             console.log("mkdir error", error);
             reject(false);
           });

         })//end promise file exists
         .catch( (err) => {
           console.log("resized image exist error", error);
           reject(false);
         });

       })//end promise createResizedImage
       .catch( (error) => {
         console.log("image resize error", error);
         reject(false);
       });

    }   ); }

export async function uploadAttachment(attachment) {

  //initialize s3 transferUtility   transferUtility.setupWithCognito(S3Options)
    .then( (result) => {
      console.log("s3 setup result", result);

      //compress the file
      let imagePath = `${dirPicutures}/${attachment.s3_key}`;
      let compressedImagePath = `${dirPicuturesCompressed}/${attachment.s3_key}`;

      imageResized = await compressImage(imagePath, compressedImagePath);

      console.log("imageResized boolean", imageResized);


    })//end promise successful s3 cognito setup
    .catch( (error) => console.log("s3 setup error", error) );

}//end of uploadAttachment
```

I am getting an error saying await is a reserved word. Appreciate if anyone can clarify what's the issue here.

I read some tutorials for Promise and am trying to implement uploads to AWS S3 after compressing an image and moving it to a particular folder using that technique to make the code more robust.

The other work around that works is by moving the code for upload inside the compressImage function where the resolve(true) is being returned.

Comment: await can only be used inside a function tagged `async` ... your await is inside a `.then` callback not marked `async` ... just `return compressImage(...etc` - in fact you never need `async` in the code you've shown

Comment: without the await I always get undefined for imageResized boolean in the console.

Comment: well, it's a promise, it shouldn't be undefined - `compressImage` should always resolve or reject - by the way, avoid the promise constructor anti-pattern you use in `compressImage`

Comment: sorry, not sure what you mean by the constructor anti-pattern.

Comment: you're wrapping a function that returns a promise in `new Promise`

Comment: new to javascript! appreciate if you can suggest the code changes. thanks

Comment: hang on, getting there

Comment: although that isn't the issue - `console.log("imageResized boolean", imageResized);` should never be undefined ... however, any call to `uploadAttachment(attachment)` **WILL** result in `undefined` as you are not returning anything

Comment: try adding `return` before `transferUtility.setupWithCognito(S3Options)` ... and `return imageResized` after you assign it

Comment: there's the actual upload to s3 that will happen after I get imageResized boolean based on that value so I won't be returning imageResized form the uploadAttachment function.

Comment: you're not returning **anything** from `uploadAttachment` ...that's where the `undefined` is coming from